# Admin search Woocommerce order by custom field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i've added a custom field to my checkout and i want to make it searchable , in order to search orders by using it.
The field is mobile phone and the code so far is :

```
function custom_admin_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    global $post;
    $order = $post->ID;
    $fields['phone']['show'] = false;
    $fields['mobile'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Mobile', 'bootstrap' ),
        'value'=>get_post_meta( $order, '_billing_mobile', true ),
        'show'  => true
    );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'custom_admin_billing_fields',10,1 );

function custom_admin_shipping_fields( $fields ) {
    global $post;
    $order = $post->ID;
    $fields['phone']['show'] = false;
    $fields['mobile'] = array(
        'label' => __( 'Mobile', 'bootstrap' ),
        'value'=>get_post_meta( $order, '_shipping_mobile', true ),
        'show'  => true
    );

    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields', 'custom_admin_shipping_fields', 11, 1);

function woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total( $search_fields ) {
    $search_fields[] = '_billing_mobile';
    $search_fields[] = '_shipping_mobile';

    return $search_fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_total' );
```

The search is not working for the mobile phone , althought it works fine for the default fields

And the code for the frontend (checkout)

```
function custom_woocommerce_shipping_fields($fields) {
    $fields['shipping_phone']   = array(
        'label'          => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
        'placeholder'    => __('Phone', 'woocommerce'),
        'required'       => false,
        'class'          => array('form-row-last'),
    );

    $fields['shipping_mobile']  = array(
        'label'          => __('Mobile Phone', 'bootstrap'),
        'placeholder'    => __('Mobile Phone', 'bootstrap'),
        'required'       => true,
        'clear'          => true,
        'class'          => array('form-row'),
    );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shipping_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_shipping_fields');

function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing_phone']['required']    = false;
    $fields['billing_mobile']   = array(
        'label'          => __('Mobile Phone', 'bootstrap'),
        'placeholder'    => __('Mobile Phone', 'bootstrap'),
        'required'       => true,
        'clear'          => true,
        'class'          => array('form-row-last'),
    );
    return $fields;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields' );
```

Comment: Updated the post including the front end code

Comment: No but they appear fine in the Admin order panel so i supposed they are ok

Comment: **For information**, this is is **a BUG in WooCommerce** found by **sarakinos**:   "It was casting search values as int so they could not exceed 10 digits. Bug patched. Dirty solution alter the woocommerce core by changing %%%d%% to %%%s%% in wc_order_search, or wait till patch is applied to a production version"…

Comment: The issue is solved or not ? I also looking for solution for order search by custom filed value

Answer (score 3):

We had the same demand to **find order by the "Tracking Code"** (from AST plugin).

Here is the code to add a custom column in search (to insert in  your *functions.php*) :

```
function woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_tracking_code($search_fields) { 
    $search_fields[] = '_woocommerce-advanced-shipment-tracking'; 
    return $search_fields;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_shop_order_search_fields', 'woocommerce_shop_order_search_order_tracking_code');
```

Result :

[image: woo custom column in orders list search]

Hope it helps.